# Zend Framework 2 and ExtJS

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, extjs4, zend-framework2

I'm looking to create an application using ExtJS client-side and Zend Framework 2 on the server side, and I have several questions:

1. Where do I put the ExtJS library? Should it go in the `application_root/vendor` folder or the `application_root/public/js` folder?
2. Where should the `app` folder be located? In the `application_root/public/js/app` folder?

Does anyone have examples of an ExtJS/ZF2 app that I could have a look at, to get an idea of folder structure?

Thanks

Comment: ext should be put in the public folder. public/js or public/script should be fine.

Comment: Did you ever find some nice examples?

Comment: @Erik No I spent quite a long time looking but never found an entire application written with ExtJS and Zend 2. Let me know if you have any luck with this!

Comment: My boss may just ask me to do this... If i do ill share what i can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application_root/vendor is reserved for 3rd party PHP libraries. Put your static snippets to approot/public folder.

If you want to separate extjs like 3rd party JS libraries from your application snippets, you can create another vendor directory for them in public, manually. For example:

```
public/js
|-- common.js
|-- main.js
|-- plugins.js
`-- vendor
    |-- bootstrap.js
    |-- bootstrap.min.js
    `-- extjs
        |-- extjs-one.js
        `-- extjs-two.js
    |-- html5-3.6-respond-1.1.0.min.js
```